# Get Drawable path of images

Tags: android, gallery, android-imageview, android-gallery

I am implementing a horizontal gallery in my `Fragment Activity`, but I can't get my images, therefore returning a `NullPointerException`:

```
LinearLayout myGallery;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    myGallery = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mygallery);

    String targetPath = "assets/";

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){ //NullPointerException here
        myGallery.addView(insertPhoto(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
}
```

And this is the path of my images:

[image]

The `NullPointerException` points at the for loop `for (File file ; files){ ...`

What is the right way to reach my folder?

Comment: This is not how Android drawables work. Use `assets` or `raw`, not `drawable-gallery`.

Comment: where is the assets folder?

Comment: ok thanks, I've followed your observations, but it still produces a `NullPointerException`

Comment: My Logcat: http://pastie.org/private/bj7brxb8o61yutcex4mw

Comment: You cannot use the File and FileInputStream classes for 'files' in assets. You have to use the assets manager an let that open an input stream to your 'files'. Google for open or copy files from assets. You could have left your images in drawables too. But if you want to list them assets is the way to go.

Comment: but I need a File, not an InputStream

Comment: I collected my comments into an answer, so you can accept it and remove it from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is... Put your images in the `assets` folder (or in `raw`).
Not in `res`.

Create the `assets` folder, if not already existing.
At the **same level** of `res` , **not inside it**.

To get your resource, then use something like this (in this case the file is under the `gfx` folder, under `assets`):

```
final InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("gfx/" + fileName);
final Drawable drw = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
```

And you have your drawable out of `assets`

---

If you want to put the resources directly into `assets` rather than adding a folder, simply chang this

```
getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("gfx/" + fileName);
```

to

```
getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(fileName);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `gfx`?

Comment: Short for `graphics`. Just a folder - call it whatever you like, i.e.: `images`. Or you can skip it totally and put the resources directly int `assets`: `....getAssets().open(fileName);`

Comment: thanks, Is it possible to get an array of `Files[]` from the drawables?

Comment: You can iterate through the file names (possibly a string array) and make an array of Drawables.

Comment: This should solve it. Your assets folder in inside of res, which is wrong.